# My code gives "ValueError: shapes (64,) and (32,) not aligned: 64 (dim 0) != 32 (dim 0)" when I try to implement the dot product

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

```
#numpy implementation of a simple RNN
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
timesteps = 100 #number of elements in a sequence
input_features = 32
output_features = 64

#generate a random np array for example as input
input_sequence = np.random.random((timesteps,input_features))

#genrate random Weight vectors
W = np.random.random((output_features,input_features))
U = np.random.random((output_features,input_features))
b = np.random.random((output_features,))

#all zero state vector
state_t = np.zeros((output_features,))

all_outputs = []

def f(input_vect,state_t):
    print(input_vect.shape)
    print(W.shape)
    output_vect = tf.keras.activations.tanh(np.dot(W,input_vect) + np.dot(U,state_t_vect) + b) 
    return output_vect

for input_t in input_sequence:
    output_t = f(input_t,state_t) #has shape (output_features,)
    state_t = output_t
    all_outputs.append(output_t)

all_outputs = np.asarray(all_outputs)
final_output = all_outputs
```

The error comes in the dot product part of the code using numpy arrays.I know that the dimensions of the arrays are going to a toss.How do I correct it?.I rechecked the code and didnt find any mistakes.

Comment: Which `dot` is the problem?  Do you understand why it's a problem?  Do you understand the array shapes?

Comment: Yes,suppose there are matrices with row and column as rXc and another matrix aXb,then we can take their dot product provided c == a.I understand that

Comment: And (a,) works with (a,).  But (a,) does not work with (c,).  That's what the error is telling us.

Comment: Okay,how do I correct it?I tried interchanging the output_features,input_features values for shape but no result.Thanks

Comment: Correct what?  You haven't even identified which `dot` and which arrays are the problem.   The correction?  Make arrays with the correct, matching, shapes.

Comment: The problem is with this  np.dot(W,input_vect)  as the shape of input_vect is (32,) and W is (64,32)

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same issue.

Your random initialization for the `state weight` matrix is done wrong

change
`U = np.random.random((output_features,input_features))`

to
`U = np.random.random((output_features,output_features))`